# Is there a public implemention of LZSS compression in C# or that can be used in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, compression

I'm looking for LZSS for decoding some packets from a game engine. If anyone could point me to a library I would be extremely happy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call on the [Allegro Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegro_library) (open source library in C developed for game development). It contains [LZSS decoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Storer%E2%80%93Szymanski) and is callable from C#.

Or you can also look at: [LZSS.c](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fidC5C19F5439764532985380F4C8008B733B587429.aspx?s=huffman) and port it over to C#, or compile it into a basic C library and then call it from C#.

Comment: Could you give an example if it being called from the library? Also can this be embedded into the C# executable? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: yes one example using this library would go a long way