# How can I extract the data from a file with c#?

Tags: c#, hex, extract, editing

I need to extract some files from an archive but this archive extension cannot be opened on c#, I know that this archive contains bmp, sound, animation and other files, any way to open it?

Comment: what is the archive extension?

Comment: At least show extension of this archive files, or show hex-dump of first bytes. Where this archive come from? There is no way to "magically extract anything from anything unknown in C#"

Comment: .pac .. from super smash bros brawl wii extensions.. tnx 4 reply

Comment: ^^ there seem to be really few infos out there for this propriatary format: http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Data_Containers#PAC.2FPCS_Files ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A quick google search shows that the format is likely to be LZSS.

In which case, check out the answers to this question: [Is there a public implemention of LZSS compression in C# or that can be used in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769047/is-there-a-public-implemention-of-lzss-compression-in-c-sharp-or-that-can-be-use)